# How does an SVG image access a Web-font when the Internet is not available?

Tags: xml, svg, webfonts, google-webfonts

I have found XML code for an SVG file [here](https://vecta.io/blog/using-fonts-in-svg).

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100">
    <defs>
        <style>
            @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400i,700,700i");
        </style>
    </defs>
    <style><![CDATA[svg text{stroke:none}]]></style>
    <text x="20" y="50" font-family="Roboto">Roboto</text>
</svg>
```

This file seems to be using a Google Web-Font called `Roboto`.

[image]

I found that the Chrome browser is able to display this font even when the Internet is unavailable.

Is this font embedded in chrome browser or in the Windows OS?

Comment: I imagine Chrome caches it somehow.